# " The constructor Window(int, int, String, Game) is undefined "

Tags: java, string, constructor, int, undefined

I am having issues with a 2D platform game. I get an error that reads what the title of the question said. Here are my Game.java and Window.java files. Please tell me what I should do.
I've tried a ton of things and I just don't know where to go or what to do. Thanks in advance :)

**Window.java**

```
package com.sam.platform.window;    
import java.awt.Dimension;    
import javax.swing.JFrame;    

public class Window
{
    public Window(int w, int h, String title, Game game)
    {
        game.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        game.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(w, h));
        game.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(w, h));

        JFrame frame = new JFrame(title);
        frame.add(game);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(true);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        game.start();
    }

}
```

**Game.java**

```
package com.sam.platform.window;

import java.awt.Canvas;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Window;
import java.awt.image.BufferStrategy;

import com.sam.platform.framework.ObjectId;

public class Game extends Canvas implements Runnable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -414187095722102896L;
    private boolean running = false;
    private Thread thread;

    public static int WIDTH, HEIGHT;
    //Object
    Handler handler;


    private void init()
    {
        WIDTH = getWidth();
        HEIGHT = getHeight();


        handler = new Handler();

        handler.addObject(new Player(100, 100, handler, ObjectId.Player));

        handler.createLevel();

        this.addKeyListener(new KeyInput(handler));
    }


    public synchronized void start(){
        if(running)
            return;

        running = true;
        thread = new Thread(this);
        thread.start();

    }

    public void run()
    {
        init();
        this.requestFocus();
        long lastTime = System.nanoTime();
        double amountOfTicks = 60.0;
        double ns = 1000000000 / amountOfTicks;
        double delta = 0;
        long timer = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int updates = 0;
        int frames = 0;
        while(running){
            long now = System.nanoTime();
            delta += (now - lastTime) / ns;
            lastTime = now;
            while(delta >= 1){
                tick();
                updates++;
                delta--;
            }
            render();
            frames++;

            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - timer > 1000){
                timer += 1000;
                System.out.println("FPS:" + frames + " TICKS: " + updates);
                frames = 0;
                updates = 0;
            }
        }
    }

    private void tick()
    {
        handler.tick();
    }

    private void render()
    {
        BufferStrategy bs = this.getBufferStrategy();
        if(bs == null)
        {
            this.createBufferStrategy(3);
            return;
        }

        Graphics g = bs.getDrawGraphics();
        //////////////////////////////////
        //Draw Here
        g.setColor(Color.black);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());

        handler.render(g);

        //////////////////////////////////
        g.dispose();
        bs.show();

    }   
    public static void main(String args[]){
        new Window(900, 900, "Hop", new Game()); //error is here "The constructor                 Window(int, int, String, Game) is undefined"

    }


}
```

Comment: how did you instantiate `Window` class?

Comment: BTW.  This there a good reason you are using AWT (i.e. Window, Canvas) and not Swing (e.g. JFrame, JPanel)?  Or, come to think of it, JavaFX.  (As I understand it Oracle are discontinuing development of Swing, from Java 1.8 onwards, in favour of JavaFX.)

Answer (score 2):

Your `Window` class is fine, but the class you're importing in `Game` is `java.awt.Window`.

You could solve this by doing new `com.sam.platform.window.Window(...)`, but I would advise against it, it will just confuse you.

Rename the class to something like `GameWindow` instead.

Comment: I just removed the import "java.awt.Window" it works fine now :)

Answer (score 2):

You have two different classes called `Window` in use in your `Game` class.  One is `com.sam.platform.window.Window`.  The other is `java.awt.Window`.  Since you have imported `java.awt.Window` into your `Game` class, it thinks you are trying to instantiate one of those (not your own `Window` class).

I suggest renaming you own class to disambiguate (and avoid confusion) to, say, `GameWindow`.

Comment: Thanks! I removed the import java.awt.Window and it works fine now! You are awesome!

Comment: Okay.  But rename your own class to something other then `Window`; you won't regret it.

Comment: Also - as per my comment above - is there a reason you are using AWT classes, and not Swing (or JavaFX)?

Comment: Whenever I import a class in eclipse it automatically labels as AWT. And I can't change the class name because I would have to re-write a lot of stuff. I have about 10 other classes using the window.class import. I think it might be easier to leave it.

Comment: @lilsam138 You need to look up 'refactoring'  Eclipse will automatically adapt the rest of the code if you rename the class using Alt+Shift+R

Comment: I'll do that later today.